# Difference using if/else vs just if before a return statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I found it hard to search for this question.

Will the else statement make any difference in the code below?

```
public string Test()
{
  if (statement) return "a";
  else return "b";
}
```

What's good practice in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, in fact they both compile down to the same IL:

```
public bool GetValue(bool input)
{
    if (input) return true;

    return false;
}

IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  brfalse.s   IL_0005
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0004:  ret         
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  ret
```

And:

```
public bool GetValue2(bool input)
{
    if (input)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

IL_0000:  ldarg.1     
IL_0001:  brfalse.s   IL_0005
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0004:  ret         
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  ret
```

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not make any difference in this case, since if the if-statement is true, it will return and never go to the `return "b";` line regardless of the if.

In this case, I usually omit the else, but I don't know if that is what the majority will do in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The *else* may be unnecessary, but personally I think it's a small price to pay to add a bit of readability and balance out the *if* logic.

Answer (score 2):

I usually prefer the variant without the `else`. While they're *functionally* equivalent, the `else` version sometimes leads to large number of indents.

```
public string Test() {
    if (statement)
        return "a";
    return "b";
}
```

There's nothing really wrong with either variant for a simple case like that, but contrast it with (for example) four checks at the start of a function (pseudocode):

```
define fn():
    if error condition 1:
        handle error 1
    else:
        if error condition 2:
            handle error 2
        else:
            if error condition 3:
                handle error 3
            else:
                if error condition 4:
                    handle error 4
                else:
                    do something
```

as opposed to:

```
define fn():
    if error condition 1:
        handle error 1
        return

    if error condition 2:
        handle error 2
        return

    if error condition 3:
        handle error 3
        return

    if error condition 4:
        handle error 4
        return

    do something
```

In my opinion, the latter is "cleaner" code.

Comment: Agreed.  And re-ordering blocks like this are so much easier than untangling `if-then-else` chains.  *shudder*

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference and likely the compiler will emit the same in both cases.  As an aside, for small checks like your example you can always use the following ([conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

```
public string Test()
{
    return statement ? "a" : "b";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all about whatever makes the clearest code.

Personally I feel that in most situations the redudant else makes the code clearer,, but others may feel differently.

Either way I would personally be using brackets though for your if/else, but others may feel that this makes there code too verbose.

```
   public string Test()
    {   
            if (statement)
            {
                 return "a";
            }
            else 
            {
                 return "b";
            }   
    }
```

or

```
   public string Test()
    {   
            if (statement)
            {
                 return "a";
            }

            return "b";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No difference, but my preference in this particular case is:

```
public string Test() {
   return statement ? "a" : "b";
}
```

In any case, I wouldn't keep the else statement, but that's mostly because I use ReSharper, which dims the else statement, and I'm a little OCD about that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

It will not make any difference. You should write how you like(ofc. stick to one pattern) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Nope ... without the else in the code it will perform the same thing

Answer (score 0):

No. They are logically the same.

```
 if(xx) return; else return;


 if(xx) return;
 return;
```